# 401 Unauthorized ajax call from angular node application calling Web Api 2 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have been able to make calls just fine to **Web Api** from an **Angular** / Node application when I use the **$sce** for an **IFrame**,  but now I want to call Web Api from jquery ajax within the application.

When I try to call it I get

**401 Unauthorized**

```
function getComments() {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:17308/Home/GetNewsComments?id=' + group, 
        type: 'Get',
        data: { id: tipId },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#commentDetail").empty().append(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("something seems wrong");
            console.log("something is wrong");
        }
    });
};
```

**FYI / BTW**

**I HAVE been able to make calls for IFrame with**

```
$scope.setTipId = function (id) {
   $scope.detailFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://localhost:17308/Home/GetNewsComments?id=" + id);
```

Can I do something similar for my jquery ajax calls from my controller?

**Update**

I even tried the "angular way"

```
$http.get('http://localhost:17308/CommentCount/').success(function (data) {
        console.log('made it');
    })
    .error(function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

I still get the 401 error...

Answer (score 1):

A call to a Web Api controller and loading an iFrame are fundamentally different things.

I suspect your controller method is actually requiring some sort of authorization.  Decorate the Web Api Controller or Controller method with the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` as seen below.  If this is not an option, your problem is you do not have a valid ASP.NET session or are not adding the token in your http calls for authorization.

```
[AllowAnonymous] //This allows all methods in the Controller to be accessed anonymously.  Both are redundant in this case.
public class CommentCountController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [AllowAnonymous] //This allows this method to be accessed anonymously . Both are redundant in this case.
   public int Get()
   {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: No, that was not it.  I tried those attributes.  I already have CORS enabled and a asp.net web Forms application is able to connect /call it fine from a different port etc...    It is something with Angular /Node application   this whole $sce.trustAsResourceUrl     HAD to be used in order to even call a MVC controller to work.  MVC controller is RESTful like Web Api, in fact Controller implements apicontroller   So I'm 99% sure it is a problem with Angular/Node application

Comment: Your issue has to be authentication methods getting crossed.  Your server code is locked down and Angular is not providing the proper credentials.  If token auth, you need to make sure your request has the token in the Authorization header of all outgoing $http calls from angular.

Comment: How do I add a token?

Comment: What is your system using to authorize?  You must be granted a token and you could append like in this tutorial -http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/